# How to remove the dragged object after I drop it in area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

Referring to the image below, when I drag the object from below to top, I want the dragged object to be removed from the bottom bar and when I press `X`, I want the object to come back in the bottom bar. But I am unable to remove the dragged object (and by extension bring it back as needed). You can see the code below or access it from [my codepen](http://This%20is%20my%20codepen%20%20%20%20%20%20https://codepen.io/jeraldpunx/pen/zLKmzE)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<p><b><i>In the text below some words are missing. Drag words from the box below to the appropriate place in the text. To undo an answer choice, drag the word back to the box below the text.</i></b></p>

<div class="row">
  <p class="given">
    He wants to get a better [blank] and earn more money. Managers set objectives, and decide [blank] their organization can achieve them. A defect can be caused [blank] negligen ce by one of the members of a team.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="divider"></div>
<br>
<div class="section">
  <section>
    <div class="card blue-grey ">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">

            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="1">the Santee, thDakota</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="2">America</span>

            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="3">Qatar</span>

            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="4">Philippines</span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.blanks {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
}

div.blanks.ui-droppable-active {
  min-height: 20px;
}

span.answers > b {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

span.given {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var given = $("p.given").text();

  var new_given = given.replace(/blank/g, '  <div class="blanks"></div>  ');
  $("p.given").html(new_given);

  function updateDroppables() {
    $("div.blanks").droppable({
      accept: "span.given",
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
      },
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        var dragedElement = ui.draggable.text();
        console.log(dragedElement);
        $(this).replaceWith(
          " <span class='answers'><b class='blue-text' rel='" +
            ui.draggable.attr("rel") +
            "'>" +
            dragedElement +
            "</b> <a href='#' class='material-icons cancel md-16'>highlight_off</a></span> "
        );
      }
    });
  }

  updateDroppables();

  $("span.given").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  $(document).on("click", "a.cancel", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .replaceWith("<div class='blanks'></div>");
    updateDroppables();
  });
});
```

Comment: Codepen or jsfiddle links are welcome if they accompany your [mcve] in the question itself, but cannot substitute it. This is because in most cases, the pen or the fiddle will be updated with the answer and will render the question less helpful for future users. In order to receive help you have to also provide help and the least you could do is keep your question relevant for others with a similar issue.

Comment: Added the code from code pen into the question to make it easier for users to answer the question. Links are not encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to remove the dragged elements after the drop and if cancelled to put it back to your container.

I made this with the `jQuery show(), hide()` functions.
After the drop happened, the belonging element will be hidden.

```
 drop: function(event, ui) {
    var dragedElement = ui.draggable.text();
    var dropped = ui.draggable;      
    dropped.hide(); //hide element
```

When 'X' is pressed, the element is removed from your text and appears in your bottom container instead.

```
$(document).on("click", "a.cancel", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var rel = $(this).prev().attr('rel');

 $(this)
  .parent()
  .replaceWith("<div class='blanks'></div>");
  updateDroppables();
 $('.btn-flat[rel='+rel+']').show(); //show element again
});
```

Please have a look at my updated codepen:

[Pen](https://codepen.io/toffler/pen/QBrwMm)